# Short story about a kitten being killed by humans and the mother cat taking revenge by trapping them in a dungeon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I once read or heard a short story (maybe from Lovecraft, but I am not sure). I am able to remember the following details:

- A single person or a couple, perhaps tourists, are in a possibly European city (because of the old city walls).
- I remember a scene very early on where the person/couple is walking through an old town or next to old city walls.
- They see a kitten, which then dies, and somehow the person/couple is at fault for that. I do not think it was on purpose, though.
- The mother of that kitten wants revenge and lures the person/couple into a torture dungeon, where they may or may not die.

It is definitely not "The Cats of Ulthar" by Lovecraft. I haven't had any luck with Google and ChatGPT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps Bram Stoker's "[The Squaw](https://literature.fandom.com/wiki/The_Squaw)" as per [Masochist gets more than he bargained for in fantasy horror story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255293/masochist-gets-more-than-he-bargained-for-in-fantasy-horror-story/255295#255295)?

> The story describes in gory detail how an American tourist in the German city of Nuremberg accidentally kills a kitten. It goes on to describe, in equally gory detail, how the kitten's mother gets revenge on the American.

The killing of the kitten is sort of accidental, the result of one member of the group throwing a rock to startle the kitten, and instead striking it dead.

> “Not me, ma’am,” said Elias P. “Why, I’m as tender as a Maine cherry-tree. Lor, bless ye. I wouldn’t hurt the poor pooty little critter more’n I’d scalp a baby. An’ you may bet your variegated socks on that! See, I’ll drop it fur away on the outside so’s not to go near her!” Thus saying, he leaned over and held his arm out at full length and dropped the stone. It may be that there is some attractive force which draws lesser matters to greater; or more probably that the wall was not plump but sloped to its base—we not noticing the inclination from above; but the stone fell with a sickening thud that came up to us through the hot air, right on the kitten’s head, and shattered out its little brains then and there. The black cat cast a swift upward glance, and we saw her eyes like green fire fixed an instant on Elias P. Hutcheson; and then her attention was given to the kitten, which lay still with just a quiver of her tiny limbs, whilst a thin red stream trickled from a gaping wound. With a muffled cry, such as a human being might give, she bent over the kitten licking its wounds and moaning. Suddenly she seemed to realise that it was dead, and again threw her eyes up at us. I shall never forget the sight, for she looked the perfect incarnation of hate. Her green eyes blazed with lurid fire, and the white, sharp teeth seemed to almost shine through the blood which dabbled her mouth and whiskers. She gnashed her teeth, and her claws stood out stark and at full length on every paw. Then she made a wild rush up the wall as if to reach us, but when the momentum ended fell back, and further added to her horrible appearance for she fell on the kitten, and rose with her black fur smeared with its brains and blood.

The relevant extract for the mother cat's revenge:

> But at that instant, with a sort of hellish scream, she hurled herself, not as we expected at Hutcheson, but straight at the face of the custodian. Her claws seemed to be tearing wildly as one sees in the Chinese drawings of the dragon rampant, and as I looked I saw one of them light on the poor man’s eye, and actually tear through it and down his cheek, leaving a wide band of red where the blood seemed to spurt from every vein.
>
> With a yell of sheer terror which came quicker than even his sense of pain, the man leaped back, dropping as he did so the rope which held back the iron door. I jumped for it, but was too late, for the cord ran like lightning through the pulley-block, and the heavy mass fell forward from its own weight.
>
> As the door closed I caught a glimpse of our poor companion’s face. He seemed frozen with terror. His eyes stared with a horrible anguish as if dazed, and no sound came from his lips.
>
> And then the spikes did their work. Happily the end was quick, for when I wrenched open the door they had pierced so deep that they had locked in the bones of the skull through which they had crushed, and actually tore him—it—out of his iron prison till, bound as he was, he fell at full length with a sickly thud upon the floor, the face turning upward as he fell.